# Random func is not working. Ball only goes one direction

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code but for some reason whenever I run it the ball only goes in one direction.

```
from tkinter import * import random import time

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()  
        
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 1
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.y = -1
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3     
        
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

ball = Ball(canvas, 'red') while 1:
    ball.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is wrong with just using `mainloop()` instead of `update_idletask()` and `update()`.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you examined the values of `self.x` and `self.y` to see if they are what you think they should be?

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle is working properly but there is some problem with your logic due to which ball always go to the left side and in the upward direction. You need to revise that. Also you must use if and elif in draw method for both x and y to stop your ball going out of the frame instead of using if for all.

Feel free to ask question incase of any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In case you ever run into issue like this, try debugging or at least printing some crucial values to double-check if these in fact are correct (same as you assumed).
And so if you would print `self.canvas_height` and `self.canvas_width` values you would notice that these are incorrect (they always return `1`).
Solution to your problem is to change these lines in your `init` function:

```py
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
```

to these lines:

```py
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_reqheight()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_reqwidth()
```